# run exe from silverlight application

Tags: .net, silverlight-5.0

I want to execute Exe from Silverlight application.

```
dynamic cmd = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.shell");               
cmd.Run(@"cmd /C C:\""Program Files (x86)""\""CounterPath""\""eyeBeam.exe""");
```

I am using the above code for the same. but facing some Issue when i deploy the silverlight application in local machine and Run with IP not from localhost.

the exe was not running. the exception is as below:
**"This Operation is not supported in the current context."**

It works perfect with local host, kindly help if you know  the solution or found any Issue with my code.

Thanks and Regards,
Ruchi Patel

Comment: Did you find any answer?